# What's the difference between chrome.identity.getAuthToken() interactive vs. non-interactive modes?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The difference between interactive an non-interactive modes as staed in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) of `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` is not so clear to me even after repeated readings.

> For a good user experience it is important interactive token requests
>   are initiated by UI in your app explaining what the authorization is
>   for. Failing to do this will cause your users to get authorization
>   requests, or Chrome sign in screens if they are not signed in, with
>   with no context. In particular, do not use getAuthToken interactively
>   when your app is first launched.

and

> Fetching a token may require the user to sign-in to Chrome, or approve
>   the application's requested scopes. If the interactive flag is true,
>   getAuthToken will prompt the user as necessary. When the flag is false
>   or omitted, getAuthToken will return failure any time a prompt would
>   be required.

1. How to initiate interactive token request by an UI (that explains the reason for authorization) in my app? How will `getAuthToken()` understand if it has been invoke from an UI?
2. "Do not use `getAuthToken` interactively when your app is first launched" - what is this caution for?
3. How do interactive & non-interactive modes differ?
4. "When the flag is false or omitted, `getAuthToken` will return failure any time a prompt would be required" - how do I know if a prompt is required or not?

Comment: There is more information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity). Maybe it is a bit clearer there.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:

1. For example, have a HTML button in your app to connect to the API:

myApp.html

```
<button id="connectMe">Connect to the API</button>
<script src="myApp.js"></script>
```

myApp.js

```
document.getElementById("connectMe").onclick = function(){
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive:true},function(token){
        if (token) // you have received authorization ...
    });
};
```

2. It is to prevent the users of your app to be presented with an authorization request screen without them knowing what the authorization is for or why your app needs it. That is why they reccommend using a clear UI element (like the button in the answer 1).
3. In interactive mode, the user will be presented the authorization screen if an authorization is needed (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#getAuthToken-prompts)). In non-interactive mode, if an authorization were needed, calling the `getAuthToken` method will return error.
4. A prompt is required when the user is not signed into Chrome or when the requested scope was not previously authorized.

In my (very limited) experience, I use `{interactive:true}` everytime: the first time it is used, the user is presented with the authorization screen. The subsequent requests are automatically handled by the identity API (if my requests return a 401 error Invalid Token, I use the same `getAuthToken` method and it fetches a new token automatically).

Comment: In my case it doesn't fetch it automatically, it rather creates a sign in popup and asks the user to authenticate and authorize the extension again. 
More details in the question below. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953850/oauth-for-gapi-avoid-authentication-and-authorization-after-initial-sign-in-fo